# Keep getting Resultset closed sql Exception

Tags: java

this is the class where error happens

```
public class Drinks extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton button;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Drinks frame = new Drinks();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Drinks() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 401, 401);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JList list = new JList();
        list.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            }

            private Component StringtoInt(String string) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
        list.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new MatteBorder(3, 3, 3, 3, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)), null));
        list.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        JLabel lblDrink = new JLabel("Drink");
        lblDrink.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        JLabel lblIngredients = new JLabel("Ingredients");
        lblIngredients.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        button = new JButton("Back");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MainMenu frame = new MainMenu();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            }
        });

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3));
```

> Here is where i believe the problem to be as you can see there are no
>   existing close statements

```
JButton btnLoad = new JButton("Load");
            btnLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    try{
                        Connection connDrink = Connections.sqlConn();
                        int countDrinks = Connections.count(); 

                        System.out.println(countDrinks);
                        for (int j = 0; j < countDrinks; j++) { 
                        String dk = "select DrinkID, Drink from Drinks where DrinkID = " + j + ";";
                        PreparedStatement pSt = connDrink.prepareStatement(dk); 
                        ResultSet rS = pSt.executeQuery();
                        System.out.println(rS.getString(2));
                        int oi = Integer.parseInt(rS.getString(1).toString());
                        `//`list.add(rS.getString(2).toString(), null);
                        }

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Always gives java.sql.SQLException: Result Set closed and I cant find where the result set is closed or if there is another error

Comment: Try calling `rS.next()` before `rS.getString(2)`. I don't think that is the cause of the set being closed, but it should be done. Also, look into [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: "as you can see there are no existing close statements" that's nothing to be proud of you know. You're supposed to close your resources :D

Comment: xD removed the close statement hoping my problem would go away

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to comment, so I'll answer here.

you should try

```
if(rS.first())// move the cursor to the first row, true if there's a row, false otherwise
    System.out.println(rS.getString(2));
```